# Extracting value of nc_pid variable residing inside function

Tags: bash, process, variable

I want to update `nc_pid` so I can use it to check if process with pid `nc_pid` is running.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function start () {
    trap 'echo "Clean up and exit"; kill $nc_pid; exit' TERM
    exec > outfile
    exec 2> errfile
    exec 0< /dev/null

    while true; do
        (nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash &>/dev/null) &
        nc_pid=$!                 # global variable nc_pid is not updated
        wait $nc_pid
        kill $nc_pid &>/dev/null
    done
}

if [ "$1" != "__forked__" ]; then
        setsid "$0" __forked__ "$@" &
        exit
else
        shift
fi

# stop or start daemon
nc_pid=999999

case "$1" in
    stop)
    killall simpled.sh
    ;;
    start)  
    if ! kill -0 $nc_pid &>/dev/null            # always false
    then
        start
    fi
    ;;
    status)
    if kill -0 $nc_pid &>/dev/null              # always false
    then
        echo "nc running"
    else
        echo "nc not running"
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo -e "\nsimpled.sh [start|stop|status]"
    ;;
esac
```

Initially `nc_pid` is set to something that will not exist normally (999999). Then I want `nc_pid` to be updated to pid of the forked `nc` process when `start()` is run. But it seems `nc_pid` is not updated at all (value stays as 999999).

So `$0 start` always starts a new instance of forked `nc` process and `$0 status` always outputs 'nc not running'.

How to fix the code so `nc_pid` has the pid of the forked `nc` process from outside of `start()`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just save nc's pid to a file and fix it that way.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function start () {
    trap 'echo "Clean up and exit"; kill $nc_pid; rm nc_pid; exit' TERM
    exec > outfile
    exec 2> errfile
    exec 0< /dev/null

    while true; do
        (nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash &>/dev/null) &
        nc_pid=$!
    echo $nc_pid > nc_pid
        wait $nc_pid
        kill $nc_pid &>/dev/null
    done
}

if [ "$1" != "__forked__" ]; then
        setsid "$0" __forked__ "$@" &
        exit
else
        shift
fi

# stop or start daemon

([ ! -f "nc_pid" ] && nc_pid=9999) || nc_pid=$(cat nc_pid) 

case "$1" in
    stop)
    killall simpled.sh
    ;;
    start)  
    if ! kill -0 $nc_pid &>/dev/null
    then
        start
    fi
    ;;
    status)
    if kill -0 $nc_pid &>/dev/null
    then
        echo -e "\nnc running: pid $nc_pid"
    else
        echo -e "\nnc not running"
    fi
    ;;
    *)  
        # when $0 is run, the help message displays then won't return to terminal until return key is pressed.
    echo -e "\nsimpled.sh [start|stop|status]" 
    ;;
esac
```

Cheers!